# Why bolted short circuit current in Arc Flash calculations much lower

Tags: transformer

Given single phase 240/120 transformers with 75 kVA rating and 2% impedance

computing using the infinite bus short cut method

75,000 / 240 / 0.02 = 15625 amp

or the long cut (with derivation) method

- kVA = 75,000
- Voltage = 240 V
- The impedance of a load that would draw 75 kVA is 240<sup>2</sup> / 75000 = 0.768 ohms.
- Transformer impedance = 0.02 x 0.768 = 0.01536
- Short circuit current = 240 / 0.01536 = 15625 amp

Now consider 20 feet of wire has resistance of about 0.002 (from an online wire impedance calc). To add them together one, one uses this

\$Total\ impedance = \sqrt {0.002^2 + 0.01536^2}= 0.01549 \ \text{A} \$.

Bolted short circuit current 20 feet away AWG 1 is 240 / 0.01549= 15494 A.

The difference with adding 20 feet of AWG 1 wire is decrease of only 1% of the short circuit current.

Now consider the Arc Flash fault calculation method [here](http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/dam/public/bussmann/Electrical/Resources/solution-center/technical_library/BUS_Ele_Tech_Lib_Electrical_Formulas.pdf).

You can try it in excel spreadsheet ([here](https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/download-center/electrical-software/fault-current-calculation)).

Input the same data.

[image]
[image]

With terminal short circuit current of 15625 A.

The short circuit current 20 feet away AWG 1 is much lower 11595 A.

Why is it much lower?

Did the arc flash method somehow give the 20 feet conductor an inductive value, but it's not part of the transformer winding.

Let's go to the Arc Flash Calculation method formulas:

at 1Ø Line-to-Neutral (L-N) Faults

f = [2 x L x I (l-l)] /[ C x n x E (l-l)]

$$ f = \frac {2 L I_{l-l}}{ C n E_{l-l}} $$

Where:

L = length (feet) of conductor to the fault.
C = constant from Table 4 of “C” values for conductors and
Table 5 of “C” values for busway.
n = Number of conductors per phase (adjusts C value for
parallel runs)
I = Available short-circuit current in amperes at beginning
of circuit.
E = Voltage of circuit.

(How did they determine C where  the bolted short circuit current is much lower using this method but high when directly computing for it. Also how did they drive f?).

Then you get \$ M = \frac{1}{1+f} \$

And multiply the transformer terminal short circuit current by M.

The result is much lower bolted short circuit current 20 feet away (AWG 1) about 25% less compare to the ballpark computations. Why? Where is the hidden impedance in the wire. Instead of 0.002, it becomes higher like 0.010, how?

Comment: I've tried to tidy up the question a bit and add some MathJAX to make the equations more legible. I'm not sure what the "f =" equation is trying to say so I've left the oringal in for now as well as the MathJAX version. If you mean \$ 2LI_{l-l} \$ then the syntax is `2LI_{l-l}`. You can also use HTML `<sub> ... </sub>` for subscript and `<sup>` for superscript as part of non-MathJAX text.

Comment: Have you considered that the wire has both a resistance and an inductance? You will want to look up the AC resistance at 50Hz and the AC inductance at 50Hz. That changes your impedance calculation.

Comment: But for 20 feet AWG 1 of straight service conductors, the AC inductance won't produce a factor since it is not in winding form. So its contribution to the bolted short circuit current at 20 feet end is insignificant.